# Is there a way to disable Python debugger's pdb library set_trace default aliases?

Tags: python, pdb

Is there a way to disable the default `pdb` library command aliases? I currently am using variables that have the same name as the `pdb` `set_trace()` shortcut aliases. For example, I have a variable named `s`, but `s` is a shortcut for `step` while using `set_trace()`. This is one default alias among many like `a` and `n` which represent `args` and `next` respectively.

So when I am trying to inspect my `s` variable by typing in the `s` command, it runs `step` instead which is not what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing Pdb documentation:

> ! statement
>
> Execute the (one-line) statement in the context of the current stack
>   frame. The exclamation point can be omitted unless the first word of
>   the statement resembles a debugger command.

This should do what you want, if I'm not mistaken